# PostMessage/SendMessage is getting blocked by the application

Tags: c++, hook, postmessage, wndproc

I'm trying to send/post a message to a certain application.

The message IS delivered, according to Spy++, however that message is internally blocked by that application.

Despite it being a game or not, how do I get around it other than writing a custom keyboard/mouse driver?

This post is quite small as it's pretty straight forward.

Things I have tried:

```
const DWORD mem = (DWORD) GetProcAddress(LoadLibraryA("USER32.DLL"), "PostMessageA") + 5;

_declspec(naked) BOOL PostMessageX(HWND hWnd, UINT Msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    _asm
    {
        mov edi, edi
        push ebp
        mov ebp, esp
        jmp dword ptr ds : [mem]
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `"internally blocked"`? Is the other application not removing the message from the queue using `GetMessage`/`PeekMessage`? Or is it not forwarding the message to `DefWindowProc`? Or are you merely observing that sending the message does not have the desired effect?

Comment: Note that games may be using the `DirectInput`/`XInput` API, which I believe does not use window/thread messages.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel for now I'm merely observing that the message does not have the desired effect. That given application is probably discarding MSLLHOOKSTRUCT messages with `LLMHF_INJECTED` set to 1. Like I said, the keyboard message does work.

Comment: So far I only got the mouse input simulation through `SendInput`, but I don't want to have the application window focused, that's why I'm not willing to use a custom driver either.